# Is it possible to map object to a List in Automapper?

Tags: collections, automapper

I have a class Foos:

```
public class Foos
{
    public string TypeName;

    public IEnumerable<int> IDs;
}
```

Is it possible to map it with AutoMapper to IList of Foo objects?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string TypeName;

    public int ID;
}
```

Comment: :) it is very possible with the http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ , that's actually one of the things that I'm using it for

Comment: @Omu I never saw this project... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omu's answer gaved me an idea how to solve the problem (+1 for suggestion). I've used ConstructUsing() method and it worked for me:

```
    private class MyProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<Foos, Foo>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
            CreateMap<Foos, IList<Foo>>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => x.IDs.Select(y => CreateFoo(x, y)).ToList());                
        }

        private Foo CreateFoo(Foos foos, int id)
        {
            var foo = Mapper.Map<Foos, Foo>(foos);
            foo.ID = id;
            return foo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well why don't you post an answer instead of hinting in comments?